# 'Column Chooser' doesn't show columns anymore

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

Suddenly the column chooser (in executing application) stopped showing available columns in GridControl. I re-installed the application on the client machine but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column chooser will always be empty until you drag a column into it at runtime or populate it at design time (via code). If you are persisting the column chooser to some kind of storage e.g. XML then your path may be incorrect.

Comment: you can also populate it in desgin-time while designing the grid's layout... and that exactly my scenario, i got about 4 grids like this grid all columns choosers display their columns correctly except this one, And i dont know why its just happened suddenly

Comment: Have you consulted DevExpress support? It could be a temp file created by the designer needs to be removed.

Comment: it turns out the the layout designer missed the columns! re-populated again

Answer (score 0):

Check that the generateMember-property is set to true for the columns in the designer.